# Spring Security 3.2 embedded ldap server ignoring ldap-server tag

Tags: security, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, spring-ldap

I am new to Spring.  I have been trying to follow the code samples in the book *Spring in Action*.  The chapter on security is poorly written and I have found numerous errors in the sample code.  Most I have figured out with the help of this awsome site, or by rtfm.  In this case, however, I am stuck.

I am using Spring 4.0, Hibernate 4.0, Spring Security 3.2 and Tomcat 7.0.47.  My Spring MVC example works fine with an in memory user repository (user-service tag), but when I try to switch over to a simple ldap service, I get the following error (copy and pasted from the Tomcat console output) when my application is loaded by Tomcat:

```
1311 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: No BaseLdapPathContextSource instances found. Have you added an <ldap-server /> element to your application context? If you have declared an explicit bean, do not use lazy-init
    at org.springframework.security.config.ldap.ContextSourceSettingPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ContextSourceSettingPostProcessor.java:42)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:265)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:170)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:381)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:293)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:663)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1642)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Nice output as it tells me I am missing the ldap-server tag.  Well I am not.  It is in a file called *spitter-security.xml* (starting on line 11):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

<ldap-server root="dc=habuma,dc=com"
             ldif="classpath:users.ldif" />

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
  <ldap-authentication-provider
                   user-search-base="ou=people"
                   user-search-filter="(uid=0})"
                   group-search-base="ou=groups"
                   group-search-filter="member={0}"  />
</authentication-manager>
  <!--
    Automatically registers a login form, BASIC authentication, anonymous authentication, 
    logout services, remember-me and servlet-api-integration.
  -->
  <http request-matcher="regex" pattern="\A/spitters\?new\Z"
        security="none" >
  </http>
  <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/resources/css/**"
                   access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/resources/images/**"
                   access="permitAll"  />
    <intercept-url pattern="/login"
                   access="isAnonymous()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/home"
                   access="isAnonymous() or hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" 
                   access="isAuthenticated() and hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**"
                   access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <form-login login-page="/login"
                login-processing-url="/static/j_spring_security_check"  
                authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=1"
                default-target-url="/home"
                always-use-default-target="true"/>
    <logout logout-url="/static/j_spring_security_logout"/>

    <!--remember-me key="spitterKey"
        token-validity-seconds="2419200" /-->    

  </http>

</beans:beans>
```

Here is my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         version="2.5" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spitter</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
      org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spitter</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>
      org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
      org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
      org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
      org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
    </listener-class>
  </listener>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
      /WEB-INF/spitter-security.xml
      classpath:dataSource-context.xml
      classpath:persistence-context.xml
      classpath:service-context.xml
    </param-value>
  </context-param>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
      org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <servlet-name>spitter</servlet-name>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Here is my spitter-servlet.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

  <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

  <mvc:annotation-driven/>

  <context:component-scan base-package="com.habuma.spitter.mvc" />

  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver">
  </bean>


  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
      <list>
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/**/views.xml</value>
      </list>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class=
"org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"
        p:maxUploadSize="500000" />
  <bean id="messageSource"
         class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
     <property name="basenames">
       <list>
         <value>/resources/ui</value>
       </list>
     </property>
   </bean>

</beans>
```

Here are the jars I have loaded in WEB-INF/lib:

```
01/15/2014  10:04 AM         2,000,557 ant-1.9.2.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM            18,333 ant-launcher-1.9.2.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM           445,288 antlr-2.7.7.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM             4,467 aopalliance-1.0.jar
01/16/2014  04:20 PM           325,112 apacheds-core-1.5.7.jar
01/16/2014  04:20 PM           186,034 apacheds-core-api-1.5.7.jar
01/16/2014  04:20 PM            11,467 apacheds-core-constants-1.5.7.jar
01/16/2014  04:20 PM            33,434 apacheds-core-entry-1.5.7.jar
01/16/2014  04:20 PM            38,741 apacheds-i18n-1.5.7.jar
01/16/2014  04:20 PM            12,406 apacheds-utils-1.5.7.jar
01/15/2014  09:54 PM            60,282 classmate-1.0.0.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM           231,320 commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM           175,426 commons-collections-2.1.1.jar
01/16/2014  04:20 PM           575,389 commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM           148,783 commons-digester-2.0.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM            68,622 commons-fileupload-1.3.jar
01/15/2014  07:11 PM           185,140 commons-io-2.4.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM            52,915 commons-logging-1.1.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM            26,202 commons-logging-api-1.0.4.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM           313,898 dom4j-1.6.1.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM            15,649 geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM            75,311 hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.4.Final.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM         5,208,917 hibernate-core-4.3.0.Final.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM           645,015 hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.0.Final.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM           113,371 hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM           377,562 hibernate-tools-4.0.0-CR1.jar
01/15/2014  09:49 PM           574,341 hibernate-validator-5.0.2.Final.jar
01/15/2014  09:04 PM         1,467,326 hsqldb-2.3.1.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM            76,551 jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM           714,194 javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM             2,497 javax.inject-1.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM            57,183 jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM            11,558 jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM            27,717 jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM            17,097 jcl-over-slf4j-1.5.8.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM           414,240 jstl-1.2.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM            15,071 jta-1.1.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM           249,028 jtidy-r8-20060801.jar
01/15/2014  01:10 PM           489,884 log4j-1.2.17.jar
01/16/2014  04:20 PM           638,294 mina-core-2.0.0-RC1.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM            52,150 persistence-api-1.0.jar
01/16/2014  04:20 PM            96,747 shared-asn1-0.9.19.jar
01/16/2014  04:20 PM            12,769 shared-asn1-codec-0.9.19.jar
01/16/2014  04:20 PM            19,647 shared-cursor-0.9.19.jar
01/16/2014  04:20 PM           183,195 shared-dsml-parser-0.9.19.jar
01/16/2014  04:20 PM            26,078 shared-i18n-0.9.19.jar
01/16/2014  04:20 PM         1,404,206 shared-ldap-0.9.19.jar
01/16/2014  04:20 PM            23,568 shared-ldap-constants-0.9.19.jar
01/16/2014  04:20 PM            32,976 shared-ldap-converter-0.9.19.jar
01/16/2014  04:20 PM            13,196 shared-ldap-jndi-0.9.19.jar
01/16/2014  04:20 PM           590,303 shared-ldap-schema-0.9.19.jar
01/16/2014  04:20 PM             6,928 shared-ldap-schema-dao-0.9.19.jar
01/16/2014  04:20 PM            27,319 shared-ldap-schema-loader-0.9.19.jar
01/16/2014  04:20 PM            20,108 shared-ldap-schema-manager-0.9.19.jar
01/16/2014  04:20 PM            44,343 shared-ldif-0.9.19.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM            25,689 slf4j-api-1.6.2.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM             7,668 slf4j-simple-1.6.2.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM           351,240 spring-aop-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM           669,267 spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM           148,444 spring-binding-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM           950,606 spring-context-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM           955,328 spring-core-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM           206,507 spring-expression-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM           419,872 spring-jdbc-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM            17,381 spring-js-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM         4,412,472 spring-js-resources-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar
01/16/2014  01:51 PM           231,729 spring-ldap-core-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM           316,834 spring-orm-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
01/15/2014  11:49 AM            81,373 spring-security-acl-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM           399,068 spring-security-config-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM           359,510 spring-security-core-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
01/15/2014  11:49 AM            20,992 spring-security-taglibs-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM           342,227 spring-security-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM           441,609 spring-test-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM           248,001 spring-tx-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM           661,567 spring-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM           522,586 spring-webflow-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM           660,682 spring-webmvc-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM            30,143 tiles-api-3.0.3.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM            11,773 tiles-autotag-core-runtime-1.1.0.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM            81,289 tiles-core-3.0.3.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM            35,366 tiles-jsp-3.0.3.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM            71,616 tiles-request-api-1.0.3.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM            17,026 tiles-request-jsp-1.0.3.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM            20,035 tiles-request-servlet-1.0.3.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM            25,059 tiles-servlet-3.0.3.jar
01/15/2014  10:04 AM            31,772 tiles-template-3.0.3.jar
01/15/2014  09:49 PM            63,777 validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
```

Any idea why getting a *simple* example (as stated in the manuals and this book) is apparently not so simple?  How do I get it to recognize what is there in the file (the file worked until I tried changing it to use LDAP)?

Answer (score 0):

After much digging I discovered I had two versions of the commons-collections jar.  When I deleted the 2.1.1 version so that I only had 3.2.1 version, this error went away.

Then I ran into the problem that the current version of Spring Security is not compatible with the current version of ApacheDS (there are classes missing in the latest version), so you really can't use an embedded LDAP server for testing with the latest and greatest releases of everything.  So much for the examples in the book and the manual.